# Which Certificate Authority certifies Android Studio generated key pairs

Tags: android, security, android-studio

I always wonder if the public key generated as a result of the key-pair creation in Android Studio gets signed or certified by a Certificate Authority provider. It ask you for almost the same data needed to make a CSR, but it does not tell you which institution is behind, I assume is google.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate that you get from Android Studio isn't signed by any CA. It's self-signed, meaning the only signature on it is from its own public key.

Comment: I know that for each resource the build-tool creates a hash, sign it with the private key and put it in a file on the Android apk bundle. Then, by the time of apk installation, the installer app checks all the resources where signed with the same private key. Is it the only purpose of app signing existance?. I thought it also used the certificate for other stuff, but I doubt it, since having a non approved certificate is useless in many security aspects.

Comment: The app signing key is used to authenticate upgrades and to allow apps to share UIDs. In both cases, all it's used for is to verify that two apk's came from the same developer, so it's not an issue that it's self-signed.